# Purpose of Match_parent attribute

Tags: android, layout

I have encountered an attribute "Match_Parent" for the first time in a code from internet.
Before this i have been using Fill_Parent and Wrap_Content.

**What i want:** What is the purpose of Match_parent attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do your reseach. A simple search will take you to 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html
which specifies that FILL_PARENT was renamed to MATCH_PARENT because it was more appropriate given what it does. MATCH_PARENT and FILL_PARENT can be used interchangeably because they refer to the same constant.